# Bloomberg/.NET: Is BFxForward available via the API?

Tags: c#, .net, bloomberg

The BFxForward functionality is available in Excel for calculating forwards, forward outrights, etc. Is it also available via the SDK for .NET? Appreciate the functionality could be replicated by simply downloading spot plus points then normalizing (etc.) but no point reinventing the wheel.

I could put this to the helpdesk but their official stance is they don't support the server API and the documentation isn't great.

Comment: Unless you can find a field that returns the data you need (and you can ask if such a field exists to the help desk) you will probably to do it manually as you describe.

Comment: @jdweng - your link is about Excel/terminal functionality, not the "SAPI" (server API) which is what I asked about.

Comment: Again, I am asking if BFxForward functionality is available via the API for .NET - I am not asking what calculations I need to make or what the formula is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You need to use this format to get the data: Base ISO/Term ISO [Market Type] [Pricing Source] [Forward Date]X[Pricing Date] Curncy

For more information type DAPI  on Bloomberg, download the PDF documentation and go to page 207.